# Pyinstaller: failing with IndexError (Kivy application)

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

If someone could help me with this that would be great, been ripping my hair out for a while now.  I have been attempting to compile a Kivy app to .exe using pyinstaller.  It works fine in my base Anaconda env, but the resulting .exe folder is 500mb... So to make it smaller I am making a new env with only desired packages.  After everything I have tried, it always ends with

> IndexError: list index out of range
>   [4160] Failed to execute script demoplayer

Here is the full error message:

```
(reflexlast) C:\Users\Jesse\reflv01\dist\demoplayer>demoplayer.exe
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Jesse\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-02-14_3
8.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32
) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil
, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "demoplayer.py", line 7, in <module>
     from pywinauto import application
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
   File "c:\users\jesse\anaconda3\envs\reflexlast\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\
loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
     exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
   File "site-packages\pywinauto\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
     them.
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
   File "c:\users\jesse\anaconda3\envs\reflexlast\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\
loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
     exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
   File "site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 42, in <module>
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
   File "c:\users\jesse\anaconda3\envs\reflexlast\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\
loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
     exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
   File "site-packages\pywinauto\controls\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
     To activate a module this way, you can edit your configuration file (in you
r
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
   File "c:\users\jesse\anaconda3\envs\reflexlast\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\
loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
     exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
   File "site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 46, in <module>
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
   File "c:\users\jesse\anaconda3\envs\reflexlast\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\
loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
     exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
   File "site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 35, in <module>
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
   File "c:\users\jesse\anaconda3\envs\reflexlast\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\
loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
     exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
   File "site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
     Activate a module in the config
   File "site-packages\comtypes\client\_code_cache.py", line 71, in _find_gen_di
r
 IndexError: list index out of range
[4160] Failed to execute script demoplayer
```

And my .spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['demoplayer.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Jesse\\reflv01'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='demoplayer',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               Tree("C:\\Users\\Jesse\\reflv01"),
                *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='demoplayer')
```

Using windows 7 64 bit, python 3.6.4 64 bit

I thought at first that this could be because of missing packages, but I have no idea how to figure out which ones... or is it something missing in my spec file?
 my base env has ~500 packages, kivy app env ~30.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok if anyone has similar issues: apparently pyinstaller has trouble with the pywinauto package.
`Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "demoplayer.py", line 7, in <module>
     from pywinauto import application`

Specifically pyinstaller cant find the comtypes folder of pywinauto.  This thread helped me fix this:

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3177